# Apache cassandra - Designing DB for an application - How to select column families and super super column families?

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra

I need to design DB for an application using cassandra. How to select column families and super column families? I mean, in RDBMS we select tables right? How to select them in case of cassandra?

Lets take an example of a normal user login app? Could someone give the design for DB?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you store your information how you intend to retrieve. Duplication and denormalization are common and expected.

The following should provide a helpful starting point for more information:
http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/data_model/index